# Flutter - Modify AppBar from a page

Tags: flutter, flutter-appbar

So I have a Flutter application with multiple pages, this is done via a `PageView`. Before this page view I create my `AppBar` so it is persistent at the top of the application and doesn't animate when scrolling between pages.
I then want on one of the pages to create a bottom App bar, but for that I need to access the App bar element, however I have no idea how to do this.

This is the main class, the page I am trying to edit the app bar on is `PlanPage`.

```
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            title: '',
            home: _handleCurrentScreen()
        );
    }

    Widget _handleCurrentScreen() {
        return StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
            stream: auth.onAuthStateChanged,
            builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
                print(snapshot);
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return SplashPage();
                } else {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return Home();
                    }
                    return LoginPage();
                }
            }
        );
    }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
      return HomeState();
  }
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
    PageController _pageController;

    PreferredSizeWidget bottomBar;

    int _page = 0;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
              bottom: bottomBar,
          ),
          body: PageView(
              children: [
                  Container(
                      child: SafeArea(
                          child: RecipesPage()
                      ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                      child: SafeArea(
                          child: PlanPage()
                      ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                      child: SafeArea(
                          child: ShoppingListPage()
                      ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                      child: SafeArea(
                          child: ExplorePage()
                      ),
                  ),
              ],

              /// Specify the page controller
              controller: _pageController,
              onPageChanged: onPageChanged
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              items: [
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.book),
                      title: Text('Recipes')
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.event),
                      title: Text('Plan')
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                      title: Text('Shopping List')
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.public),
                      title: Text("Explore"),
                  ),
              ],
              onTap: navigationTapped,
              currentIndex: _page,
          ),

      );
  }

    void onPageChanged(int page){
        setState((){
            this._page = page;
        });
    }

    void setBottomAppBar(PreferredSizeWidget appBar) {
        this.bottomBar = appBar;
        print("setBottomAppBar: "+ appBar.toString());
    }

    /// Called when the user presses on of the
    /// [BottomNavigationBarItem] with corresponding
    /// page index
    void navigationTapped(int page){

        // Animating to the page.
        // You can use whatever duration and curve you like
        _pageController.animateToPage(
            page,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            curve: Curves.ease
        );
    }

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        initializeDateFormatting();

        _pageController = PageController();
    }

    @override
    void dispose(){
        super.dispose();
        _pageController.dispose();
    }
}
```

The `PlanPage` class looks like this

```
class PlanPage extends StatefulWidget {
    var homeState;

    PlanPage(this.homeState);

    @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        return _PlanState(homeState);
    }

}

class _PlanState extends State<PlanPage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<PlanPage>, SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
    var homeState;
    TabController _tabController;

    _PlanState(this.homeState);

    @override
    bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        //homeState.setBottomAppBar(_buildTabBar());

        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                bottom: _buildTabBar(),
            ),
            body: TabBarView(
                controller: _tabController,
                children: Plan.now().days.map((day) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: MealType.values.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                            var mealType = MealType.values[index];
                            return Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(
                                        mealType.toString().substring(mealType.toString().indexOf('.')+1),
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            //decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                            fontSize: 30.0,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                    Column(
                                        children: day.meals.where((meal) => meal.mealType == mealType).map((meal) {
                                            return RecipeCard(meal.recipe);
                                        }).toList(),
                                    )

                                ],
                            );
                        }
                    );
                }).toList(),
            )
        );
    }

    Widget _buildTabBar() {
        return TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            isScrollable: true,
            tabs: List.generate(Plan.now().days.length,(index) {
                return Tab(
                    child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                            Text(DateFormat.E().format(Plan.now().days[index].day)),
                            Text(DateFormat('d/M').format(Plan.now().days[index].day)),
                        ],
                    ),
                );
            }, growable: true),
        );
    }

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();

        _tabController = new TabController(
            length: Plan.now().days.length,
            vsync: this,
            initialIndex: 1
        );
    }
}
```

However the way it works now, makes it show 2 app bars.[[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it's a not a best practice to have two nested scrollable areas. Same for two nested Scaffolds.

That said, you can listen to page changes ( `_pageController.addListener(listener)` ) to update a `page` state property, and build a different `AppBar.bottom` (in the `Home` widget, so you can remove the Scaffold in `PlanPage`) depending on the page the user is viewing.

-EDIT-

In your `Home` widget you can add a listener to the `_pageController` like so:

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController()
        ..addListener(() {
            setState(() {});
        });
}
```

to have your widget rebuilt every time the user scrolls within your `PageView`. The `setState` call with an empty function might looks confusing, but it simply allows you to have the widget rebuilt when `_pageController.page` changes, which is not the default behavior. You could also have a `page` state property and update it in the `setState` call to reflect the `_pageController.page` property, but the result would be the same.

This way you can build a different `AppBar.bottom` depending on the `_pageController.page`:

```
// in your build function

final bottomAppBar = _pageController.page == 2 ? TabBar(...) : null;

final appBar = AppBar(
    bottom: bottomAppBar,
    ...
);

return Scaffold(
    appBar: appBar,
    ...
);
```

Comment: I can't really get it to work tbh. 
I can't figure out where I should build my TabController so I can still supply it to the  `AppBar.bottom`.

Comment: You can simply move it to the `Home` widget and pass it down to the `PlanPage` as a constructor parameter.

Comment: Doesn't feel that elegant to have all that logic in my Home widget, when that logic is specific to the PlanPage, also another one of the pages will need a Tabcontroller. So it doesnt matter that the Tabcontroller is in another state object then the one who actually uses it?

Comment: No wait, you have to display a different `AppBar.bottom` depending on which page from the `PageView` in the `Home` widget the user is viewing right? So in the `Home` widget you will have the `pageController` with the listener and the `tabController` will remain in the `PlanPage`.